# Deleting specific rows containing 0.00.. in the last column

Tags: matlab

Is there a way I can delete specific rows within a data array within MATLAB? What would be the best command to look into?

Answer (score 0):

Let

```
a =

     1     2     3
     4     5     0
     7     8     9
    10    11     0
```

then

```
a(a(:,end)~=0,:)
```

returns the rows of `a` which do not end with a `0` so you could write

```
a = a(a(:,end)~=0,:)
```

There's probably an even simpler approach which I haven't seen, but don't worry there will be a Matlab expert along soon.

Answer (score 0):

You should check out logical indexing and `[]`. I don't have MATLAB available, but I think this should work:

```
A(A(:, end) == 0, :) = [];
```

`A(:, end) == 0` finds all rows where the last column is zero. `[]` is used to delete these rows.

If you can't guarantee that the values are exactly zero, you should not use `==`, but rather use `<` and `>`. If you only have positive numbers and zero, you can use `< tol`, where `tol` is a small number you want to compare against.

You can also do it other way, like this:

```
A = A(A(:, end) ~= 0, :);
```